# why does my sql query work in sqldeveloper but not from the command line using sqlcl?

Tags: command-line, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlcl

```
select * from test where test like '%test%'
```

This returns the expected data using sqldeveloper, but from the command line using sqlcl, when i type this command and hit enter, i just see a 2.  If I hit enter again I see a 3.

What am I missing here?  I see nothing in the sqlcl docs that covers this.

Comment: I'm guessing the 2, and 3, are prompting me to enter additional queries?

Comment: More of the same query, not additional queries. A new line doesn't indicate that the statement is complete - otherwise multiline (and nicely formatted) queries would be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's behaving [the same as SQL*Plus does](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#i1039357). You've entered one line of text into the command buffer but you haven't told the client that it's a complete statement or told it to [execute it](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref269). It's showing the line number prompt to show it's expecting more input.

You can either end the statement with a semicolon, or put a slash (`/`) on a new line on its own; from that documentation:

> **Ending a SQL Command**
>   You can end a SQL command in one of three ways:
>
> - with a semicolon (;)
> - with a slash (/) on a line by itself
> - with a blank line
>
> A semicolon (;) tells SQL*Plus that you want to run the command. Type the semicolon at the end of the last line of the command ... and press Return or click Execute. SQL*Plus processes the command and also stores the command in the SQL buffer. ... If you mistakenly press Return before typing the semicolon, SQL*Plus prompts you with a line number for the next line of your command. Type the semicolon and press Return again or click Execute to run the command.
>
> A slash (/) on a line by itself also tells SQL*Plus that you wish to run the command. Press Return at the end of the last line of the command. SQL*Plus prompts you with another line number. Type a slash and press Return again or click Execute. SQL*Plus executes the command and stores it in the buffer.

SQL Devleoper supports these too, using a semicolon (by default) as the SQL termination character, and allowing that or a slash to terminate a statement. It allows you to omit it from the last statement in a script though, which SQL*Plus doesn't - the statement will never be run in that case. I think SQLcl behaves the same as SQL*Plus for that too.

(I realise SQLcl is not exactly the same, but most of the SQL*Plus documentation applies to SQL Developer and to its more recent sibling SQLcl. You can read more about it at [ThatJeffSmith's blog](http://www.http://thatjeffsmith.com).)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need to terminate your query with a semicolon.

```
select * from test where test like '%test%';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are loading the buffer and the tool is prompting you for the next line.  To execute what is in the buffer, type a slash ('/') and press enter.

Comment: Why are you voting for this answer?  Alex Poole has the most comprehensive and informative answer and deserves your vote more!

Comment: Because I can't vote for my own answer, and yours is useful too (and more succinct) *8-)

Comment: @Alex Poole - :-)  Looks like we voted for each others answers. I was considering deleting this answer as yours is more complete.