# How can I drop and re-create a pluggable database in Oracle DB 18c XE?

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus, oracle18c

I'm a Newbie to Oracle DB 18c (coming from MS SQL Server), and I want to create a pluggable database if it doesn't already exist.

I read through numerous specs about [control statements](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS388), [CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6010.htm#CCHBFIDF) and [DROP PLUGGABLE DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_8028.htm#SQLRF55699), and according to these documents, I believe I done everything alright.

But when I execute the following script using Oracle 18c XE SQLPlus REPL on Linux by means of `@/tmp/test.sql`:

```sql
ALTER SESSION SET CONTAINER=CDB$ROOT;

DEFINE DB_NAME = 'MYDB'
DEFINE DB_ADMIN = 'sa'
DEFINE DB_PWD = 'myPwd'

BEGIN
    IF SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v$pdbs WHERE name = '&DB_NAME' > 0 THEN DROP PLUGGABLE DATABASE &DB_NAME INCLUDING DATAFILES; END IF;
END;

CREATE PLUGGABLE DATABASE &DB_NAME ADMIN USER &DB_ADMIN IDENTIFIED BY &DB_PWD ROLES=(dba);
```

SQLPlus outputs:

```
SQL> @/tmp/test.sql

Session altered.

  6
```

... and doesn't continue from there.

What did I do wrong?

PS: The database in question already exists, so it should get dropped first and then be re-created.

Comment: Nothing to do with PDBs, but [you need a slash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37867383/266304) (`/`) on a line on its own to terminate and run your PL/SQL block. But, you can't run DDL statically from PL/SQL; the `drop` statement would have to be [dynamic SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801594/266304).

Comment: Well the whole concept of dropping and recreating a database is an anti-pattern in Oracle. Besides that SQL Server and Oracle **do not** necessary even mean the same thing by the term. Apparently what SQL Server terms a database Oracle terms a schema; stemming from older versions of SQL Server which did not support schema. Actually the drop & recreate is an anti-patter for any database object in Oracle. I suggest taking a look at [Migrate your mindset too](https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/migrate-your-mindset/). While it refers to Postgres it applies equally to any database mitigation.